# Project build error after successful import

Tags: jbossfuse

I'm importing already exisiting maven JBOS Fuse 6.3 camel project into Jboss Developer Studio. After successful import i'm getting following error,

I'm geeting this error in parent POM

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jboss.quickstarts.eap:jboss-quickstart-parent:6.4.0.GA: Failure to transfer org.jboss:jboss-parent:pom:8 from http://
 maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-ga-repository has 
 elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss:jboss-parent:pom:8 from/to jboss-ga-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/
 techpreview/all): maven.repository.redhat.com and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

### Parent POM.xml

```
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
```

-->
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.jboss
        jboss-parent
        8
        
    
    org.jboss.quickstarts.eap

```
<artifactId>jboss-quickstart-parent</artifactId>
<version>6.4.0.GA</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>JBoss EAP Quickstart: Parent</name>
<description>JBoss EAP Quickstarts Parent</description>
<url>http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/get-started/</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<properties>
    <!-- A base list of dependency and plugin version used in the various quick starts. -->
    <version.jboss.maven.plugin>7.4.Final</version.jboss.maven.plugin>

    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.com.mycyla.license>2.5</version.com.mycyla.license>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your apps to a local JBoss EAP container -->
        <!-- Disabling it here means that we don't try to deploy this POM! -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.maven.plugin}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
            <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.com.mycyla.license}</version>
            <configuration>
                <header>${basedir}/dist/license.txt</header>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>target/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>.clover/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/license*</exclude>
                    <!-- Exclude specific Quickstarts -->
                    <exclude>petclinic-spring/**</exclude>
                    <!-- Javascrip Libraries -->
                    <exclude>**/jquery*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/angular*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/qunit*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/backbone*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/lodash*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/modernizr*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/yepnope*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/mobile-nav*</exclude>
                    <!--Other libraries -->
                    <exclude>**/*glyphicons*/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*cordova*/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <headerDefinitions>
                    <headerDefinition>dist/headerdefinition.xml</headerDefinition>
                </headerDefinitions>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- All the modules that require nothing but JBoss Enterprise
                Application Platform or JBoss EAP -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>default</name>
                <value>!disabled</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <!-- All the modules that require nothing but JBoss Enterprise
                Application Platform or JBoss EAP -->
            <module>app-client</module>
            <module>bean-validation</module>
            <module>bean-validation-custom-constraint</module>
            <module>bmt</module>
            <module>cdi-alternative</module>
            <module>cdi-decorator</module>
            <module>cdi-interceptors</module>
            <module>cdi-injection</module>
            <module>cdi-portable-extension</module>
            <module>cdi-stereotype</module>
            <module>cdi-veto</module>
            <module>ejb-asynchronous</module>
            <module>ejb-in-ear</module>
            <module>ejb-in-war</module>
            <module>ejb-remote</module>
            <module>ejb-security</module>
            <module>ejb-security-interceptors</module>
            <module>ejb-throws-exception</module>
            <module>ejb-timer</module>
            <module>ejb-multi-server</module>
            <module>greeter</module>
            <module>helloworld</module>
            <module>helloworld-jms</module>
            <module>helloworld-mbean</module>
            <module>helloworld-mdb</module>
            <module>helloworld-mdb-propertysubstitution</module>
            <module>helloworld-rs</module>
            <module>helloworld-singleton</module>
            <module>helloworld-ws</module>
            <module>hibernate3</module>
            <module>hibernate4</module>
            <module>kitchensink</module>
            <module>kitchensink-ear</module>
            <module>kitchensink-jsp</module>
            <module>kitchensink-ml</module>
            <module>kitchensink-ml-ear</module>
            <module>log4j</module>
            <module>logging</module>
            <module>logging-tools</module>
            <module>mail</module>
            <module>numberguess</module>
            <module>payment-cdi-event</module>
            <module>picketlink-sts</module>
            <module>servlet-async</module>
            <module>servlet-filterlistener</module>
            <module>servlet-security</module>
            <module>shopping-cart</module>
            <module>tasks</module>
            <module>tasks-jsf</module>
            <module>tasks-rs</module>
            <module>temperature-converter</module>
            <module>websocket-hello</module>
            <module>xml-dom4j</module>
            <module>xml-jaxp</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- All the quickstarts that require Postgres to be running -->
        <id>requires-postgres</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>requires-postgres</name>
                <value>!disabled</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>cmt</module>
            <module>jts</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- All the quickstarts that have weird requirements around deployment that Maven can't handle -->
        <id>complex-dependencies</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>complex-dependencies</name>
                <value>!disabled</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>cluster-ha-singleton</module>
            <module>inter-app</module>                
            <module>jax-rs-client</module>
            <module>jts</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- All the quickstarts that require the "standalone-full" profile
            to be in use -->
        <id>requires-full</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>requires-full</name>
                <value>!disabled</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>helloworld-mbean</module>
            <module>helloworld-mdb</module>
            <module>helloworld-mdb-propertysubstitution</module>
            <module>jta-crash-rec</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- All the quickstarts that require the xts to be enabled -->
        <id>requires-xts</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>requires-xts</name>
                <value>!disabled</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>wsat-simple</module>
            <module>wsba-coordinator-completion-simple</module>
            <module>wsba-participant-completion-simple</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- All the quickstarts that don't actually use Maven. Don't
            activate this profile! We just include this for completeness. -->
        <id>non-maven</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>forge-from-scratch</module>
            <module>h2-console</module>
            <module>jts-distributed-crash-rec</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas to try:
 - Try building your project from the command line, to make sure all is well that way.
 - It looks like you're using a 'quickstart', which is a great idea.  These work best if they are in the original directory (with the rest of the other quickstarts), it helps get the parent resolution right.
 - If you're afraid of making your quickstart directory 'dirty' with your own applications, don't be.  It's easy to make a copy of an existing quickstart as a base to build your app on.  Just give them all a unique name prefix (to help organization) and name it likewise in the Maven GAV in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

jboss-parent pom is available through Maven Central at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/jboss-parent/8/

I am wondering why it doesn't resolve for you. Maybe try to build on command line as already suggested and force Maven to update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I point it to Maven 3.4 version. It worked. Previosuly I was using Maven 3.0.1 version .

Comment: please see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.3/pdf/Deploying_into_a_Web_Server/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Deploying_into_a_Web_Server-en-US.pdf